# How to detect mouse click in python 3 on linux?

Tags: python

I am very new to python, and I want to be able to detect mouse click events across the entire screen.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150497/pyqt4-detect-global-mouse-click) is closest to what I want, however none of the answers are very descriptive.

How can I do this?

Comment: I would probably vote this up no matter what you had asked just because you appear to be Gandalf asking a Linux question, but I also happen to find the question pertinent.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [LINK][1] But this needs sudo rights.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855823/get-mouse-deltas-using-python-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can handle mouse input using the lib [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) (code sample from github) :

```
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent

def fibo():
    a = 0
    yield a
    b = 1
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a+b
        yield b

class Clickonacci(PyMouseEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        PyMouseEvent.__init__(self)
        self.fibo = fibo()

    def click(self, x, y, button, press):
        '''Print Fibonacci numbers when the left click is pressed.'''
        if button == 1:
            if press:
                print(self.fibo.next())
        else:  # Exit if any other mouse button used
            self.stop()

C = Clickonacci()
C.run()
```

otherwise, you can do it with the `Xlib` lib : [Python Xlib catch/send mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147653/python-xlib-catch-send-mouseclick?rq=1)